# After executing a user_defined function i am getting an error

Tags: r

I have 27 states of India for which a water quality has to be tested and plotted.

```
state_1 <- subset(train,train$State.Name=="ANDHRA PRADESH")
ANDHRA <- as.data.frame(table(state_1$District.Name,state_1$Quality.Parameter,state_1$Year),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
str(ANDHRA)
names(ANDHRA) <- c("District.Name","CHEMICAL","YEAR")
an <- ggplot(ANDHRA,aes(ANDHRA$CHEMICAL,ANDHRA$Freq,fill=ANDHRA$District.Name))
an+geom_bar(stat="identity",position = "dodge")+facet_grid(.~ANDHRA$YEAR)+
labs(title="TREND of Chemical Compostion in Andhra Pradesh Villages",x="Chemicals",y="Number Of Cases",fill="Districts in Andhra Pradesh")
```

So i created a user defined function and it loads into the global environment with no error.

```
district_analysis<-function(a,b,d) {
b<- subset(train,train$State.Name=="a")
d<- as.data.frame(table(b$District.Name,b$Quality.Parameter,b$Year),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(d) <- c("District.Name","CHEMICAL","YEAR")
an <- ggplot(d,aes(d$CHEMICAL,d$Freq,fill=d$District.Name))
an+geom_bar(stat="identity",position = "dodge")+facet_grid(.~d$YEAR)+labs(title=paste0("TREND of Chemical Compostion in ", a, " Villages"),x="Chemicals",y="Number Of Cases",fill=paste0("Districts in", a)) 
return(an) }
```

so i pass the data with arguments,but i get this error.

```
> district_analysis(KERALA,bb,dd)
Error in labs(title = "TREND of Chemical Compostion in ", a, " Villages",  : 
object 'KERALA' not found
Called from: labs(title = "TREND of Chemical Compostion in ", a, " Villages", 
x = "Chemicals", y = "Number Of Cases", fill = "Districts in", 
a)
Browse[1]> n
```

> 

what might be the reason?

**edited**

------now the error------
It seems its not identifying "KERALA" as object.

Comment: As the error says, the number of columns in 'd' is 3 whereas you are passing a vector of 4 elements as `names`

Comment: you have numerous problems with strings and quotes - in your function, `have:train$State.Name=="a"` where you probably want a. Also, you should probably be quoting your 'KERALA' input

Comment: you are absolutely right but when i pass the arguments with double quotes also. i am getting a plot with nothing on it.Can you check the  code. i believe in the title tag also its not returning the value

Answer (score 0):

The error is straight forward. You need to define 3 names and not 4 (I don't see `CHEMICAL`/`Freq` in the table you are creating one line above the when with the error)

Comment: yes , i have edited that. now it is not able to identify the state name i pass.Please help.